# how to return last inserted id in MySQL procedure

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I use the procedure for user registering

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `regist`(IN login VARCHAR(20), IN password VARCHAR(32), IN ip VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `ip`) VALUES (login, password, ip);
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

but how to make the procedure return last inserted id?

Answer (score 1):

I've added a OUT parameter in your procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `regist`(IN login VARCHAR(20), IN password VARCHAR(32), IN ip VARCHAR(15), OUT lastId INT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `ip`) VALUES (login, password, ip);
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So how to call & get it in procedure?

Comment: Are data inserted into `users` table?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql it's   `LAST_INSERT_ID()`